# Testing android applications

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm new to testing.I've developed a application,now i need to test.I googled about testing for some time,learnt ,what different types of testing are there in general.I wrote few test cases.

Three things,i would like to know,

1. Is there any different types of testing for android,if yes,can you give me some links which could help me to refer.
2. How do generally a android user test his apps,Will he uses test frame works or generally write test cases and testing that on real phone to see how they are performing.
3. Is there any sample test cases written document which will give me some basic idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integration testing I use [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/). It is a nice convenient layer on top of the build in [instrumentation testing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html). These Tests need to be running in an emulator or on a real device. It is recommended in both cases to have an extra test project (producing an additional APK) that depends on the project under test.

Personally I like to partition my app so I have one or more libraries that do not depend on Android specific classes and can therefore be tested in a regular JVM using [JUnit](http://junit.org/).

There is a third way to test and that is by mocking the android classes and have the tests run in a JVM. I have not yet used it but I hear [Roboelectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) is a framework that allows for this kind of testing.

Comment: :Thanks for answering to my question but i had few more uestions too,Should we use test frame work to test or we can use test cases and test whether it is givng correct o/p in the device.Is there any alternative w/o using test frame works.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you rephrase it? What I recommended are test frameworks.

Comment: :Two types of testing are there.one is using test frame works other is app developer writing test cases and doing testing manually.Which one is correct.With out using test frames work,is there any other way to test the app is my question.

Comment: I have to admit I never tested without any framework. I used at least junit. I think you would have to put manual testing code inside the APK. Wouldn't you? I would not recommend putting your test code inside the APK. On one hand you'd have to make sure its not called by accident and on the other hand it adds unnecessary size to the APK.

Comment: When I think about it. I have been testing without any framework. By implementing a main Method in classes that did not have one. I would not recommend that for Android. Reasons stated in my previous comment. Size and accidental execution.

Answer (score 0):

Android Monkey tool can be a handy little tool. I find it handy the pseudo random fashion is handy for generating unusual use cases.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html

Comment: :I'm not talking about unusual test cases,i'm talking for all test cases,how would a developer test,with frame work or by writing manual test cases then testing it on real device.